# How to get details from email header?

Tags: python, email-parsing

This is my testing email. Named `aa.eml`

```
Received: from abcd
 Thu, 26 Sep 2019 07:31:55 +0000
Message-ID:<123>
From: TEST@ <abc-def.com donotreply@abc-def.com>
To: TEST <test@test.com>
Subject: Spam Test for Wednesday, September 25, 2019
Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2019 07:31:19 +0000
Reply-To: TEST <abc-def.com donotreply@abc-def.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: Multipart/related; charset=Windows-1252;
 boundary="00B105B8_message_boundary"
```

I'm using `email.parser.BytesParser()` to get `EmailMessage` object.

My code:

```py
>>>from email import policy, parser
>>>aa_email = parser.BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(open("aa.eml", 'rb'))
>>>aa_email['from']
'<>'
>>>aa_email['reply-to']
'TEST <"abc-def.com donotreply"@abc-def.com>'
```

The reason why I use this `BytesParser` is I can get specific information of a header, like:

```py
>>>aa_email['reply-to'].addresses
(Address(display_name='TEST', username='abc-def.com donotreply', domain='abc-def.com'),)
```

You can see that `['from']` and `['reply-to']` just different at a `@` symbol and make me cannot get `['from']` information like `['reply-to']`.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this (without regex)? Thanks all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear because there is no way to parse input which is not at all well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but too long for a comment.

I have no direct workaround (except manual parsing), because the testing email is not conformant with the RFC 2822 (referenced in the Python Standard Library) nor with the more recent RFC 5322. And the Python Library expects conformant headers.

According to the RFCs, the `From` header field contains an address (or a group of addresses). Here the content pretends to be a simple address in the format *display_name  angle_addr*. The *angle_addr* part (`<abc-def.com donotreply@abc-def.com>`) looks valid, but not the *display_name* part (`TEST@`).

The RFC mandates the *display_name* part to be a *phrase* containing *atoms* or *quoted strings*. And atoms cannot contain *special characters* like `@`. Because of that the `From:` header field should have been writen as:

```
From: "TEST@" <abc-def.com donotreply@abc-def.com>
```

This one can successfully be parsed by the Python library.

Anyway it looks close to a bug for me, because the library silently ignores the offending field with no errors or warnings, and I could find no option to detect the problem.

Comment: I would upvote this if it didn't then also make the question harder to delete.

Comment: @tripleee , Ballesta, Thanks for your useful comment, this example based on my current message which I'm working on. It quite long so I removed most of them (and change some name), just keep my issues (format) to showing here. I also remove `@` in `reply-to` too to make it more visual.

Comment: As your comment, that format of `from` is invalid. So I should parse as a string to handle it?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "handle". The only sane Python script I can propose is `raise ValueError('Input is not a valid email message')`. The problem with invalid data is that you cannot guess the correct data from it without additional input.